# DJANGO ModuleNotFound: INSTALLED_APPNAME during gunicorn wsgi deployment

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, wsgi

I'm setting up a wsgi.py and DockerFile to deploy my django app in DigitalOcean, but I'm getting the following errors during deployment phase after successful build.

I have django apps created by `manage.py startapp XXX` each named 'users' and 'documents'. From the error trace, I think there is a problem with the path since it is not detecting the apps from my "INSTALLED_APPS" config.

#### Error Log

```
-07-31 05:49:23]   File "/code/scraft-server/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]     from configurations.wsgi import get_wsgi_application  # noqa
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/configurations/wsgi.py", line 8, in <module>
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 223, in create
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]     import_module(entry)
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[2022-07-31 05:49:23] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users'
```

#### file tree

```
monorepo
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── backend-server
│   ├── users //(created with startapp)
│   ├── documents //(created with startapp)
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── common.py
│   │   ├── local.py
│   │   ├── production.py
│   ├── ...
├── docker-compose.yml
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
├── users
├── urls.py
├── wait_for_postgres.py
└── wsgi.py
```

#### wsgi.py

```py
import os

from configurations.wsgi import get_wsgi_application  # noqa

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

#### config.production.py

```py
import os
from .common import Common

class Production(Common):
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        # ...
        # My apps
        "users",
        "document",
        # etc
        "corsheaders",
        "gunicorn",
    )
    SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY")
    # all other configs are set inside config.common.py
```

#### DockerFile

```
FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE backend-server.config.production
ENV DJANGO_CONFIGURATION Production

# Allows docker to cache installed dependencies between builds
COPY ./requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Adds our application code to the image
WORKDIR /code/backend-server
COPY backend-server .  
WORKDIR /code

EXPOSE 8000

# Run the production server
CMD newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn --bind localhost:$PORT --access-logfile - backend-server.wsgi:application
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your project does not recognize your application which is the users. please change your application to look like this.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'document.apps.DocumentConfig',    
]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/applications/